# How can I center an arbitrary string over a sprite?

Tags: java, graphics

Eyesore:

[image]

The problem is, the text should be exactly centered over the player, I want something like this:

[image]

My code to draw username above the player is:

```
g.drawString(username,(int) playerX,(int) playerY);
```

I can just do `playerX-(some number of pixels)`, but this won't work all the time, because if the player makes his name something that has fewer characters, it will not be centered any more.

How can I make the user-provided String 'username' always be centered above the player sprite?

Comment: General strategy is going to involve getting the width of the string that's being drawn.  I don't use java myself (and you don't specify what library/framework you're using to draw, so I can't even Google to find out), but there will almost certainly be a function like 'getStringWidth' or similar, which will tell you how many pixels wide the string will be when drawn.

Comment: What graphics library are you using?

Comment: I am using graphics from awt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out this page : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/text/measuringtext.html

You must measure the string width in pixels, so that you will be able to offset the position to a suitable value. With Java 2D, that i assume you are using, considering the code sample you gave, that can be done like that for instance :

```
FontMetrics metrics = g.getFontMetrics(font);
int width = metrics.stringWidth(username)
g.drawString(username,(int) playerX - width/2,(int) playerY);
```

Where font is your Font object

Considering that you use your sprite x left coordinate, you may also have to use it's width to center perfectly the string (or it will be centered over the left side of the sprite)

```
g.drawString(username,(int) playerX - width/2 + SPRITE_WIDTH/2,(int) playerY);
```

Comment: I am using Graphics from awt. Thanks, I'll try this when I get home.

Comment: Doesn't work: 

  g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
  
  FontMetrics fm = g.getFontMetrics(g.getFont());
  if(username != null) width = fm.stringWidth(username);
  if(username != null){
   g.drawString(username,(int) x-width/2,(int) y);
  }

Gives me a : http://prntscr.com/3i6s95

Not exactly half. It doesn't work very well with smaller usernames

Comment: Not sure, but i suppose that the string is being centered over the left corner of your sprite :

Try something like this :
    g.drawString(username, (int) x - width/2 + SPRITE_WIDTH/2, (int) y)